# Creating an Installer that Creates + Sets up SQL server Database in Install - WPF/

Tags: .net, wpf, sql-server, windows-installer

I have a program that uses WPF/.Net and connects to a SQL Server Database. I am at the deployment stage, and I am trying to create an installer that creates + sets up my database my application can connect to every time it is run. Using Visual Studio 2010. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to install a local version of SQL?  There are many versions of SQL - be specific.

Comment: Are you assuming the sql server application is already installed? If so you can run a command line script to build your db: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750278/sql-server-2008-create-database-script-schema-data-with-command-line

Comment: @Blam Using MSFT SQL Server. I was assuming visual studio would create something that allows a user without any installation of SQL Server to pull/push to the database created on installation. Was a bad assumption.

Comment: @MikeParkhill I was assuming that SQL server was already installed, and for the machines I will install the software (school project), they will SQL server installed already actually. My problem now is that my connection string in the application is hard coded to somewhere on my machine's directory, and I would like the database to be created, set up, and have the program connect to the instance.

Comment: How can VS can talk to SQL if SQL is not installed?  Look to embedded CE.  IN your dev environment what does it connect to?

Comment: It connects to a sql server instance, the server name is .\sqlexpress.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio doesn't support this directly. To install SQL Server you can add it as a prerequisite, but setting up the database requires [custom actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (custom code written by you).

An easy solution would be to use a commercial setup authoring tool which supports SQL scripts and databases. Here is a list which can get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software